# git smudge/clean keyword expansion producing wrong results

Tags: git

I'm trying to get some info into committed files (I'm a CVS switcher), but the results always seem to be for the previous commit.

I tried using the $Date$ example in Progit.pdf's Keyword Expansion, with similar results. Here are my scripts, which are supposed to replace $Log$ with the commit SHA1 and date, and then restore $Log$ on the way back in:

### smudge

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#
data = STDIN.read
info = `git log --pretty=format:"%h on %ad " -1`
puts data.gsub(/\$Log.*\$/, '$Log: ' + info.to_s + ' $')
```

### clean

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#   
#
data = STDIN.read.tr("\r","\n")
data.sub!(/\$Log.*\$/,"$Log$")     # Replace expanded string, if any, with $Log$
puts data
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `STDIN.read` may wind up reading a _lot_ of data -- be careful when working with large files.

Comment: Also, note that the `smudge` filter is only run when the file is checked out...so they won't run if you add/commit a file.  If you remove it and then run `git checkout <file>` the filter will be applied.  For what it's worth, you example appears to work fine for me.

Comment: You should use shell scripts with sed to swap out values.